# Unable to run spring boot batch job from PCF CLI with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line-interface, spring-batch, pcf

I am trying to run a spring boot batch job from PCF CLI using the command:

```
cf run-task TEST_APP “.Java-buildpack/oracle_jre/bin/java org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher -D jobName=job1”
```

But the task is failing with the following error in logs:

```
ERR Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
ERR Caused by: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with open_jdk_jre...

```
cf run-task TEST_APP ".java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher -D jobName=job"
```

Seems you have oracle_jre so give it a try:

```
cf run-task TEST_APP ".java-buildpack/oracle_jre/bin/java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher -D jobName=job1"
```

Comment: Tried running using the above command but same error

Comment: Is it possible fir you to ssh into the container and check if there is any change in the path? Under /app you should be able to navigate further to .java-buildpack etc.  Which PCF version are you on?

Comment: I don’t have permissions to ssh into the container. I will ask our server admin to check. Thank you.